# Spring cannot get draw, start and length from DataTables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, datatables

I know I am doing something wrong, but I can't find where. If you could look at my code, and tell me, why these parameters are null. I am trying to apply serverside pagination to my app and in DataTables. System.outs didn't work, so my "request" is wrong or these parameters are null.

Maybe someone has useful links for articles about pagination etc? Manual from datatables didn't help me.

Spring Controller:

```
package com.example.controller;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.dao.SeriaDao;
import com.example.model.Seria;


@RestController
public class WebController extends HttpServlet{

    @Autowired
    SeriaDao sed;


    @GetMapping("/tabelka")
    public List<Seria> showTable()
    {
        return sed.findAll();
    }

    int draw = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int length = 20;

    @GetMapping("/pgTabelka")
    public Map<String,Object> pgTable(HttpServletRequest request)
    {

        Map<String,Object> json = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        if(request.getParameter("draw")!=null)
        {
            draw = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("draw"));
            System.out.println("draw dziala");
        }
        if(request.getParameter("start")!=null)
        {
            start = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("start"));
            System.out.println("start dziala");
        }
        if(request.getParameter("length")!=null)
        {
            length = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("length"));
            System.out.println("length dziala");
        }
        int totalRecords = sed.recordsTotal();

        List<Seria> serie = sed.findPart(start, length);

            json.put("draw", draw);
            json.put("recordsTotal", totalRecords);
            json.put("recordsFiltered", totalRecords);
            json.put("data", serie);


        return json;
    }
}
```

Html index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Data Viewer</title>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="tab" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>file</th>
        <th>cassid</th>
        <th>categoryid</th>
        <th>datefrom</th>
        <th>frequency</th>
        <th>markers</th>
        <th>unit</th>
        <th>feed</th>
        <th>userid</th>
        <th>createdate</th>
        <th>changedate</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
<script>
    $('#tab').DataTable( {

        ajax: {
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            url: '/pgTabelka',
        },
        columns: [
            {data: "id"},
            {data:"name"},
            {data:"file"},
            {data:"cassid"},
            {data:"categoryid"},
            {data:"datefrom"},
            {data:"frequency"},
            {data:"markers"},
            {data:"unit"},
            {data:"feed"},
            {data:"userid"},
            {data:"createdate"},
            {data:"changedate"}
        ]
    } );

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON from Postman(shorted):

```
{
"recordsFiltered": 488,
"data": [
{
"id": 41,
"name": "Average Weekly Earnings of All Employees: Total Private in Corpus Christi, TX (MSA)",
"file": "SMU48185800500000011.csv",
"cassid": "1d2e556b-031e-4c6f-aec4-981c4e907324",
"categoryid": 3,
"datefrom": "2006-12-31",
"frequency": 5,
"markers": null,
"unit": "$ per Week",
"feed": "Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets",
"userid": null,
"createdate": "2016-10-15T23:38:49",
"changedate": "2017-01-09T00:50:01"
},
{
"id": 42,
"name": "Harmonized Index of Consumer Prices: Audio-Visual, Photographic, and Information Processing Equipment for Cyprus",
"file": "CP0910CYM086NEST.csv",
"cassid": "6df5b8d5-ec39-4860-930f-a8b355cce37a",
"categoryid": 3,
"datefrom": "1995-12-31",
"frequency": 5,
"markers": null,
"unit": "Index 2015=100",
"feed": "Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets",
"userid": null,
"createdate": "2016-10-15T23:38:49",
"changedate": "2017-02-16T11:35:04"
},
{
........
}
],
"draw": 0,
"recordsTotal": 488
}
```

Comment: You need table body not just thead, so the results can be displayed.

Comment: @ZoranPandovski you are wrong, resluts are displayed. My problem is that all parameters (draw, start, length) are null. I cannot get them from DataTables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables was not sending parameters.

I realised i have done terrible mistake in DataTables configuration:

**WRONG**

```
$('#tab').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        url: '/pgTabelka',
    },
    columns: [
        {data: "id"},
        {data:"name"},
        {data:"file"},
        {data:"cassid"},
        {data:"categoryid"},
        {data:"datefrom"},
        {data:"frequency"},
        {data:"markers"},
        {data:"unit"},
        {data:"feed"},
        {data:"userid"},
        {data:"createdate"},
        {data:"changedate"}
    ]
} );

</script>
```

**GOOD**

```
<script>
    $('#tab').DataTable( {

        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/pgTabelka',
        },
        columns: [
            {data: "id"},
            {data:"name"},
            {data:"file"},
            {data:"cassid"},
            {data:"categoryid"},
            {data:"datefrom"},
            {data:"frequency"},
            {data:"markers"},
            {data:"unit"},
            {data:"feed"},
            {data:"userid"},
            {data:"createdate"},
            {data:"changedate"}
        ]
    } );

    </script>
```